# Save Dataframe changes to the same xlsx file using pandas (append)

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to save changes to the same xlsx file without overwriting it,

What I use to read the file

```
import pandas as pd 

file = 'path'
df = pd.read_excel(f"{file}", 'sheet')
```

This has overwritten my file

```
df.to_excel(path)
```

According to Pandas team the following could be used

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/excel/_base.py#L800-L814

```
 mode : {{'w', 'a'}}, default 'w'
        File mode to use (write or append). Append does not work with fsspec URLs.
    {storage_options}
        .. versionadded:: 1.2.0
    if_sheet_exists : {{'error', 'new', 'replace', 'overlay'}}, default 'error'
        How to behave when trying to write to a sheet that already
        exists (append mode only).
        * error: raise a ValueError.
        * new: Create a new sheet, with a name determined by the engine.
        * replace: Delete the contents of the sheet before writing to it.
        * overlay: Write contents to the existing sheet without removing the old
          contents.
```

If someone could guide me through this I would be highly appreciative :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually went through the documentation and got it figured.. guess I was too hasty with the question here

Will leave the solution here in hopes it'll help someone else

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(file,
engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"{sheets[counter]}")
```